# Handling "as" in R package builds

Tags: r, package

Is there a standard convention for handling `as()` coercion in package builds that is CRAN compliant? What I am wanting to do is have an if statement `if(any(class(x) == "sf")) { x <- as(x, "Spatial") }` that will allow and coerce sf class objects that are passed to a function that uses sp classes. I do not really want to import the entire sf library but also cannot use sf::as() because it is not exported from the namespace so, how to I deal with importing this coercion method without importing the package?

Comment: I don't see an `as` function in the `sf` NAMESPACE.  There are `as.[method]`s, but not a straight `as`.  What function in particular are you wanting to use from `sf`?

Comment: I was after the method but, it looks like "as_Spatial" is exported from the sf namespace so, I can just call that function explicitly. This use to be buried and not exported, so was only available via the as method.